# how to check the validity of an XML file against a DTD file in java?

Tags: java, xml, jdom, jdom-2

I am working with Java and I want to check if an XML file is valid against a DTD.
Assuming that we do have a DTD file "myDtdFile.dtd", I want to check if certain XML file "myXmlFile.xml" is valid against the same definitions proposed in the DTD file. (ie: there is no violation in the set of tags included in the xml file)
is there any way to do it ?
i tried this already :

[how to check the validity of an XML file against a DTD file in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29267539/how-to-check-the-validity-of-an-xml-file-against-a-dtd-file-in-java)

but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

finally, i found the right answer. check this guys

http://www.herongyang.com/XML/DTD-Validation-of-XML-with-DTD-Using-DOM.html